# Using Spacy functionalities for Arabic Language

Tags: spacy, named-entity-recognition, information-retrieval, information-extraction, spacy-transformers

I want to train a model on NER annotation and then use it to perform information extraction.

Also I want to see how spaCy's built-in visualizer detected the NEs in the document for Arabic language, and how a dependency parse encodes grammatical information by using spaCy's dependency visualizer to help in extracting the relations.

Basically, I'm transforming the work that has been done in [this link](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1U6x-3OVCGtx9CBZvzdJi8mhTxCx8k4Ie?usp=sharing) but for Arabic language and with some modifications on the NER task, as I want to train the model on my NER classes.

```
import spacy
import spacy_transformers
nlp = spacy.blank("ar") # empty English pipeline
# create the config with the name of your model
# values omitted will get default values
config = {
    "model": {
        "@architectures": "spacy-transformers.TransformerModel.v3",
        "name": "aubmindlab/bert-large-arabertv02"
    }
}
nlp.add_pipe("transformer", config=config)
nlp.initialize() # XXX don't forget this step!
doc = nlp("فريك الذرة لذيذة")
print(doc._.trf_data) # all the Transformer output is stored here
```

Is that possible? and if so, what are the steps that I need to do in order to accomplish the task?

I appreciate any helpful examples and resources.

Comment: You should go through the spaCy course, which shows how to get started with the library and train an NER model. You shouldn't have to make significant changes for Arabic. I would also recommend not using Transformers at first, just to make sure everything's working. https://course.spacy.io/en/

Comment: Also note there is a bug related to displaCy display in RTL languages, unfortunately. https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/4854